# GetInterfaces() returns generic interface type with FullName = null

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

Can anyone explain to me why GetInterfaces() in the below code returns an interface type that has FullName = null?

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type[] interfaces = typeof (Data<>).GetInterfaces();
        foreach (Type @interface in interfaces)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name='{0}' FullName='{1}'", @interface.Name, @interface.FullName ?? "null");
        }
    }
}

public class Data<T> : IData<T>
{
    public T Content { get; set; }
}

public interface IData<T>
{
    T Content { get; set; }
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
Name=IData`1' FullName='null'
```

I kind of expected:

```
Name=IData`1'
FullName='ConsoleApplication2.IData`1'
```

Please enlighten me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/haibo_luo/type-fullname-returns-null-when

> Update: Microsoft documentation is improved:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx

> Type.FullName is null if the current instance represents a generic type parameter, an array type, pointer type, or byref type based on a type parameter, or a generic type that is not a generic type definition but contains unresolved type parameters.

Here is an example of a situation where `Type.FullName` is `null`, boiled down from the documentation:

```
    [Fact]
    public void FullNameOfUnresolvedGenericArgumentIsNull()
    {
        Type openGenericType = typeof(Nullable<>);
        Type typeOfUnresolvedGenericArgument = openGenericType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        Assert.Null(typeOfUnresolvedGenericArgument.FullName);
    }
```

Comment: Straight links to external sites might provide the answer, but there is inherent risk in providing a link from SO. What happens if the link becomes invalid, 404, gets edited etc. The answer to the question is lost. It would be very beneficial to provide an explanation in the answer with a link to support the answer is helpful. This follows the general SO guidelines.

Comment: @Hooligancat i added a small quote from the documentation plus and example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method to fix the type reference:

```
public static Type FixTypeReference(this Type type)
{
    if (type.FullName != null)
        return type;

    string typeQualifiedName = type.DeclaringType != null
        ? type.DeclaringType.FullName + "+" + type.Name + ", " + type.Assembly.FullName
        : type.Namespace + "." + type.Name + ", " + type.Assembly.FullName;

    return Type.GetType(typeQualifiedName, true);
}
```