# Why are generic type definitions in C# not equatable to those they inherit from

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I had expected the following test to pass, but it doesn't.

```
var iCollectionType = typeof(ICollection<>);
var listSuper = typeof(List<>).GetInterfaces().First(i => i.GUID == iCollectionType.GUID);
Assert.That(listSuper, Is.EqualTo(iCollectionType));
```

I know that the same type loaded in 2 different app domains aren't considered equal. I don't see how that could be happening in the above code, but I checked the AssemblyQualifiedName of each type, and sure enough they're different.

```
iCollectionType.AssemblyQualifiedName.Dump();
//System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

listSuper.AssemblyQualifiedName.Dump();
//null
```

When I tested further I found that this is the case for all generic interfaces in the list of interfaces for a generic type definition, and also for generic base types; but not for non-generic interfaces and base types, nor for constructed generic types.

I'd like to know why generic type definitions I get using typeof seem to be incompatible with those in their inheritance and base type list. It seems less than awesome.

The closest I've come to finding an answer was on the [Type.AssemblyQualifiedName page of MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) where I found the following quote.

> If the current Type object represents a generic parameter, this property returns null.

I'm fairly sure that doesn't apply here since I don't think these are generic parameters, but I could be wrong.

The above was running in LinqPad v5.02.03 if that makes a difference.

Comment: There was a very similar question a week or so ago, but I can't remember what it was called.

Comment: I had a bit of a look and couldn't find anything, but it's late here and maybe I couldn't think of the right terms.

Comment: I found it: [Why a generic type definition implemented interfaces lose type information?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776433/why-a-generic-type-definition-implemented-interfaces-lose-type-information). The answer there I think should answer your question.

Comment: I don't actually think that is the same. That answer talks about the fact that `typeof(List<int>)` and `typeof(List<>)` are different, which I understand. In this question none of the types I'm working with is ever a constructed type. They're all generic type definitions.

Comment: Does this part of the accepted answer not deal with it though - "When you say `class List<T> : IList<T>` then the `IList<T>` part is not equal to `typeof(IList<>)` because it is already specialized to `T`"? That is, the `ICollection<>` interface that belongs to `List<>` is bound to `List`s type parameter?

Comment: Wait, I think you're right where he talks about the `IList<T>` part in `List<T>: IList<T>` being specialised to `T`. That would explain it. When I call `listSuper.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` I end up with `iCollectionType` again. That's not what I expected, but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: Ha, beat me to it @Damien_The_Unbeliever . I'll work out how to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: It';s worth reading this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117090/getinterfaces-returns-generic-interface-type-with-fullname-null, and the link in the accepted answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2006/02/17/534480.aspx

Comment: It's actually the only way that really makes sense, if you think about it - it's not the *most* specific type possible, but it's definitely not as generic as the simple `IList<>`. For example, generic type constraints are stored in that type - it's the difference between e.g. `MyList<T> : IList<T> where T : MyBaseType` and `MyList<T> : IList<T>`. And the exact same thing applies to generic methods (and methods on generic types). Remember that everything has to be reflectable - a method on `A<>` has generic parameters, a method on `A<string>` *doesn't* - even when the methods aren't "generic"!

Comment: I agree, it does make sense now that I've had time to sit on it. I still think it's a fairly curious case though. I mean, what IS it? It's not a generic type definition, and it doesn't seem like a constructed generic type because it's bound to a generic type parameter (I think), not an actual concrete type. Is that where `Type.ContainsGenericParameters` comes in? The type says it's a constructed generic type and it contains generic params, where that's false when it's constructed with a concrete type.

Comment: My previous comment was answered by the link posted by @DavidArno. I should really learn to read before typing my musings out for the world.